# When passing parameters to getopt, does the order must same as the parsing order?

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

I want to use getopt to parsing my input, such as --count=123 --range=456 --err

Here is my test code:

```sh
argv=$(getopt --name `basename $0` --options '' --longoptions err::,count:,range: -- "$@") 2>&1 || show_usage
eval "set -- ${argv}"
echo "debug> [$argv]"

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        "--count")
            echo "HitCount=$2"
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            shift 2
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            ;;
        "--range")
            echo "ScanRange=$2"
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            shift 2
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            break
            ;;
        "--")
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            shift
            echo "debug> [$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8]"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            show_usage
            break
            ;;
    esac
done
```

test1: it's good

```sh
./getopt.sh  --count=1234 --range=5678
debug> [ --count '1234' --range '5678' --]
HitCount=1234
debug> [--count/1234/--range/5678/--///]
debug> [--range/5678/--/////]
ScanRange=5678
debug> [--range/5678/--/////]
debug> [--///////]
```

test2: **I only change the order in command line, but it cannot parsed "--count"**. I don't know why?

```sh
./getopt.sh --range=5678 --count=1234
debug> [ --range '5678' --count '1234' --]
ScanRange=5678
debug> [--range/5678/--count/1234/--///]
debug> [--count/1234/--/////]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When passing parameters to getopt, does the order must same as the parsing order?

No.

> it cannot parsed "--count". I don't know why?

You have `break` before `"--"` so it breaks the loop.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to delete break in --range checking. Thank you